# How to boost up SQL query execution time in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have used below query to fetch records from database.

```
SELECT
    [dbo].[CamelCase](ISNULL(B.City, '')),
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(250), ISNULL(B.Addr1, '') + '/' + ISNULL(B.Addr2, '') + '/' + ISNULL(B.Area, '') + '/' + ISNULL(B.City, '') + '/' + ISNULL(B.State, '')),
    ISNULL(B.YardName, ''),
    DATEADD(HH, 10, CONVERT(DATETIME, A.Date_From)),
    DATEADD(HH, 17, CONVERT(DATETIME, A.Date_To)),
    '',
    ISNULL(B.Zone, ''),
    '',
    '',
    ISNULL(B.ContactPerson, ''),
    B.Mobile,
    ISNULL(B.EMailId, ''),
    '',
    A.AucCode,
    [dbo].[CamelCase](B.State),
    B.Pincode,
    [dbo].[CamelCase](ISNULL(B.City, ''))
FROM dbo.TBL_Auction A
JOIN dbo.TBL_PLACE B ON A.Auc_Place_Fk_Id = B.Place_Pk_Id
```

Indexes in TBL_Auction Table:

```
Index Name ------------------- + Column Name -------- + Index Type
PK__PASS_AUC__8BC43C38517CE882 |  Auc_Pk_Id           | CLUSTERED   
IX_PASS_Created_On             |  Created_On          | NONCLUSTERED
Unq_Pass_Auction               |  Auc_Code            | NONCLUSTERED
Unq_Pass_Auction               |  Auc_Place_Fk_Id     | NONCLUSTERED
FK_Pass_Place                  |  Auc_Place_Fk_Id     | NONCLUSTERED
```

Indexes in TBL_Place Table:

```
Index Name ------------------  + Column Name------- +  Index Type
PK__PASS_PLA__4F8634950F7A1AFB | Place_Pk_Id        |  CLUSTERED
IX_PASS_PLACE_I                | Place_Area         |  NONCLUSTERED
IX_PASS_PLACE_I                | Place_City         |  NONCLUSTERED
IX_PASS_PLACE_I                | Place_State        |  NONCLUSTERED
IX_PASS_PLACE_I                | Place_Country      |  NONCLUSTERED
IX_PASS_PLACE_I                | Place_Pincode      |  NONCLUSTERED
IX_PASS_PLACE_IV               | Place_Shrt_Code    |  NONCLUSTERED
```

But above query takes infinite time to return result.

I have created all necessary indexes for my joining tables. Even after that also optimizer chooses index scan instead of index seek. You can check the indexes list in my question for two tables. How to force the optimizer to choose index seek?

When I use **Select *** instead of specifying **Select Column Names**, at that time query result has been returned within 1 seconds. What is the problem when I specify column names in Select query?

**Edit:-**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CamelCase]
(@Str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(2000)
  SET @Str = LOWER(@Str) + ' '
  SET @Result = ''
  WHILE 1=1
  BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('% %',@Str) = 0 BREAK
    SET @Result = @Result + UPPER(Left(@Str,1))+
    SubString  (@Str,2,CharIndex(' ',@Str)-1)
    SET @Str = SubString(@Str,
      CharIndex(' ',@Str)+1,Len(@Str))
  END
  SET @Result = Left(@Result,Len(@Result))
  RETURN @Result
END
```

[image]

Comment: Although this won't help you much, but if `select *` returns almost in an instant, then perhaps you could try `select *` to a temp table, and select your desired columns from there. This is a nasty workaround, and not a good explanation, but wanted to give my two cents.

Comment: My guess is the functions you call in the select list is affecting your execution. Try selecting columns but without the CamelCase (3 times per row) and other functions

Comment: You'll need to post the definition of `dbo.CamelCase`

Comment: @aardila, I have updated my dbo.CamelCase function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your camel case function will go into an infinite loop if passed `NULL` as the only way of exiting is `PATINDEX('% %',@Str)= 0` and that will evaluate to unknown.

You need to fix that.

You can use `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT` though for safety I would handle it explicitly too.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CamelCase] 
               (@Str VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT, 
     SCHEMABINDING
AS
  BEGIN
      IF @Str IS NULL
        RETURN NULL;

        /*.... Rest of function*/
```

Comment: @IdoGal - yes it is.  **above query takes infinite time to return result.** - the first question should be "is it possible for the scalar UDF to enter an infinite loop" and the answer is "yes". Of course when the OP uses `*` they don't call the function.

Comment: @MartinSmith, I have changed some other UDF function for changing CamelCase for State and City columns. Query output comes quickly. Thank you for guiding me in correct direction.

Comment: @MartinSmith, As per changes suggested by you, I have changed my CamelCase UDF function. Works like a charm.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Without changing UDF Function, I have modified in my query. I have missed to mention IsNull for State column. Select [dbo].[CamelCase](IsNull(B.State, '')), [dbo].[CamelCase](ISNULL(B.City, '')). Query works perfectly.